# How to disable Visual Studio unhandled exception

Tags: javascript, exception, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on javascript on Visual Studio 2013, and there would always a pop up windows which says unhandled exception.
[image: unhandled exception]

Can I disable some particular exception? I have tried to open the Exceptions and uncheck the box for that particular exception, but it still pops up when I debug. Is there any solution for this?
[image: exception]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to open the debug and option and settings, go to debugging and check enable just my code. The problem is fixed.